# Got stuck on Dirac's equation related by Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, dirac-equation

Currently I'm reading the book Quark & Leptons : An introductory course in modern particle physics by F. Halzen & Alan D. Martin.

And have been on Chapter 5. Dirac's Equation. In section 5.6 Bilinear covariant, i got stuck on it.
Particularly on this part:
Consider Dirac's equation in two frames ($x$ and $x'$) related by Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$.
$$i\gamma^\mu\frac{\partial\psi (x)}{\partial x^\mu}-m \psi(x) = 0$$
$$i\gamma^\mu\frac{\partial\psi' (x')}{\partial x'^\mu}-m \psi'(x') = 0$$

where $x'=\Lambda x$. There must exist a relation
$$\psi'(x')=S\psi (x)$$

Subtituting this relation into second Dirac equation, and demanding consistency with the first Dirac equation, will obtain
$$S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S = \Lambda_\nu^\mu \gamma^\nu$$
where we have used $\partial/\partial x^\mu = \Lambda_\mu^\nu \partial/\partial x'^\nu$

I'm asking for anybody who would be pleased to explain in clear derivation and obtain these equation $S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S = \Lambda_\nu^\mu \gamma^\nu$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\partial_\mu = \partial/\partial x^\mu$ is covarinat:
$$
\partial_\mu' =  (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu{}_\mu \partial_\nu ,
$$
where $\Lambda^{-1}$ is the inverse matrix of $\Lambda$.

We can transform the second Dirac equation as
\begin{align}
0 &= (i \gamma^\mu \partial'_\mu - m) \psi'(x') \\
&= [i \gamma^\mu (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu{}_\mu \partial_\nu - m] S \psi(x) .
\end{align}
By multiplying $S^{-1}$ from left, we obtain
$$
[i S^{-1} \gamma^\mu S (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu{}_\mu \partial_\nu - m] \psi(x) = 0 .
$$
Comparing with the first Dirac equation, we obtain
$$
S^{-1} \gamma^\mu S (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu{}_\mu = \gamma^\nu .
$$
By multiplying $\Lambda^\rho{}_\nu$, we obtain
$$
\Lambda^\rho{}_\nu \gamma^\nu = S^{-1} \gamma^\mu S (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu{}_\mu \Lambda^\rho{}_\nu
= S^{-1} \gamma^\mu S \delta^\rho_\mu = S^{-1} \gamma^\rho S .
$$